# When do signals get assigned in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Considering this code:

```
architecture synth of my_entity is
    signal a : std_logic;
begin

    a <= c and d;
    b <= a and c;

end synth;
```

Is the second line going to respect that `a` changed in the other process or are all signals only at the end of *architecture* assigned?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060635/how-does-signal-assignment-work-in-a-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful with your terminology.  When you say `a` changed in the other "process", that has a specific meaning in VHDL (process is a keyword in VHDL), and your code does not have any processes.

Synthesizers will treat your code as:

```
a <= c and d;
b <= (c and d) and c;
```

Simulators will typically assign a in a first pass, then assign b on a second pass one 'delta' later.  A delta is an infinitesimal time delay that takes place at the same simulation time as the initial assignment.

Note this is a gross generalization of what really happens...if you want full details, read up on the documentation provided with your tool chain.

Comment: We learned that those lines above are called *implicit processes*, is there another name for them?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly You are correct. Concurrent statements get elaborated as processes. Hence, your signal assignments could be designated as processes.

Comment: @Charles behavior is not tool dependent, but it is well defined by the VHDL standard. Here is a blog post that explains about delta cycles: http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel

Answer (score 1):

> Is the second line going to respect that a changed in the other
>   process or are all signals only at the end of architecture assigned?

It sounds like you are thinking of signal behaviour *within a single process* when you say this.  In that context, the signals are not updated until the end of the process, so the `b` update will use the "old" value of `a`

However, signal assignments not inside a `process` statement are executed continuously, there is nothing to "trigger" an architecture to "run".  Or alternatively, they are all individual separate implied processes (as you have commented), with a sensitivity list implied by everything on the "right-hand-side".

In your particular case, the `b` assignment will use the new value of `a`, and the assignment will happen one delta-cycle after the `a` assignment.

For a readable description of how simulation time works in VHDL, see Jan Decaluwe's page here:

http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel

And also this thread might be instructive:

https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.vhdl/browse_thread/thread/e47295730b0c3de4/d5bd4532349aadf0?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=vhdl+concurrent+assignment#d5bd4532349aadf0