# VHDL rising_edge function instead uses falling edge?

Tags: vhdl

I've been trying to write an simulate a toggle flip-flop for a while now. I can't find anything wrong with my code here, but for some reason when I simulate it, the output toggles on the falling edge of the clock instead of the rising edge. Is there a mistake that I've missed?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TFF is
  Port (EN, T, CLK : in std_logic; 
        Q : out std_logic);
end TFF;

architecture Behavioral of TFF is

signal temp_q : std_logic := '0';

begin
    proc1 : process (EN, T, CLK)
    begin
        if EN = '1' then
            if rising_edge(CLK) then
                if T = '1' then temp_q <= (not temp_q);
                else temp_q <= temp_q; end if;
            end if;
        else Q <= temp_q; end if;
        Q <= temp_q;
    end process proc1;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from a more consistent code indentation style.

Comment: Can you please add your test bench?

Comment: by the way, apart from all the better solutions proposed, you could also fix this by adding `temp_q` to the process sensitivity list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flip flop implementation with process. \[VHDL\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659138/flip-flop-implementation-with-process-vhdl)

Comment: Besides either needing q_temp in the sensitivity list as JHBonarius suggests or moving the the assignment to Q to it's own process/concurrent statement, you don't need T in the sensitivity list. It's inside the if statement with the rising edge condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It toggles on falling edge, because in rising_edge it uses old value of `temp_q` (remember, that assigning to signals is NOT done at once, it is scheduled, and done at the end of the process), and because you have assignment outside of `rising_edge()` if, it is done on falling edge.

You shouldn't have anything outside `rising_edge()` if. This process launches every time clock edge changes, so also on falling edge. You also don't need anything apart from CLK on the sensitivity list. Assigning to `Q` also does not has to be done in process - it can be done concurrently. You can also move `temp_q <= temp_q;` to the beginning of the process body, so it will be always scheduled, and in case of `T = '0'` it will be inverted. Lastly, you should first check for rising_edge, and then for clock enable.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TFF is
  Port (EN, T, CLK : in std_logic; 
        Q : out std_logic);
end TFF;

architecture Behavioral of TFF is

signal temp_q : std_logic := '0';

begin

Q <= temp_q;

    proc1 : process (CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if EN = '1' then

                temp_q <= temp_q;

                if T = '1' then 
                    temp_q <= not temp_q;
                end if;

            end if;
        end if;
    end process proc1;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think that fixed my problem!

Comment: You don't need this: `temp_q <= temp_q;`, because VHDL signals retain their value until another value is assigned to them. It would be much better to delete that line.

Comment: Isn't that without this line tool will infer latch?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `Q <= temp_q` whenever the process is called, means one of the signals in the sensitivity list changes. This means your assigning `temp_q <= not(temp_q)` or `temp_q <= temp_q` respectively on the rising edge of the clock and then assign that value to Q on the falling edge as this is when the process is run the next time. The thing would look even stranger when synthesized as it's asynchronous.

I'm not a hundred percent sure what you want to achieve. If you want a complete synchronous design then your `if rising_edge(CLK)` should be the top IF statement. Further the T signal is not required in the sensitivity list as a change of this signal does not affect any output signal directly.