# Errors with Counters in FPGA Resetting (using VHDL)

Tags: counter, vhdl, reset, fpga

I am trying to make a design with multiple counters cycling from 0 to 109. However, the counters do not reset at 109, but rather 127 (their max value) when on the FPGA. They do work in simulation though. Below is my code:

```
speaker_processing_r : process(us_clock)
begin
    if(rising_edge(us_clock)) then   
        if(i_reset = '1') then
            output_counter_r_0 <= 0;
            output_counter_r_1 <= (sample_period);
            output_counter_r_2 <= (sample_period*2);
            output_counter_r_3 <= (sample_period*3);
            output_counter_r_4 <= (sample_period*4);    
            data_r_0           <= X"00";
            data_r_1           <= X"00";
            data_r_2           <= X"00";
            data_r_3           <= X"00";
            data_r_4           <= X"00";                                            

        else    

            --Output Conditions based on delays calculated or inserted
            if(output_counter_r_0 = 2) then
                data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(0);
            elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_1) then
                data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(0);
            elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_2) then
                data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(0); 
            elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_3) then
                data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(0);
            elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_4) then
                data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(0);
            elsif(output_counter_r_0 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
                output_counter_r_0    <= 0;
            end if;

            if(output_counter_r_1 = 2) then
                data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(1);
            elsif(output_counter_r_1 = delay_1) then
                data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(1);
            elsif(output_counter_r_1 = delay_2) then
                data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(1); 
            elsif(output_counter_r_1 = delay_3) then
                data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(1);
            elsif(output_counter_r_1 = delay_4) then
                data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(1);
            elsif(output_counter_r_1 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
                output_counter_r_1    <= 0;
            end if;

            if(output_counter_r_2 = 2) then
                data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(2);
            elsif(output_counter_r_2 = delay_1) then
                data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(2);
            elsif(output_counter_r_2 = delay_2) then
                data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(2); 
            elsif(output_counter_r_2 = delay_3) then
                data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(2);
            elsif(output_counter_r_2 = delay_4) then
                data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(2);
            elsif(output_counter_r_2 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
                output_counter_r_2    <= 0;
            end if;

            if(output_counter_r_3 = 2) then
                data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(3);
            elsif(output_counter_r_3 = delay_1) then
                data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(3);
            elsif(output_counter_r_3 = delay_2) then
                data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(3); 
            elsif(output_counter_r_3 = delay_3) then
                data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(3);
            elsif(output_counter_r_3 = delay_4) then
                data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(3);
            elsif(output_counter_r_3 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
                output_counter_r_3    <= 0;
            end if;

            if(output_counter_r_4 = 2) then
                data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(4);
            elsif(output_counter_r_4 = delay_1) then
                data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(4);
            elsif(output_counter_r_4 = delay_2) then
                data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(4); 
            elsif(output_counter_r_4 = delay_3) then
                data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(4);
            elsif(output_counter_r_4 = delay_4) then
                data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(4);
            elsif(output_counter_r_4 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
                output_counter_r_4    <= 0;
            end if;

            output_counter_r_0 <= output_counter_r_0 +1;
            output_counter_r_1 <= output_counter_r_1 +1;
            output_counter_r_2 <= output_counter_r_2 +1;
            output_counter_r_3 <= output_counter_r_3 +1;
            output_counter_r_4 <= output_counter_r_4 +1;

        end if;     
    end if;
end process;
```

All of the delay (`delay_1`, `delay_2`, `delay_3`, `delay_4`) signals are generics as well as `sample_period`. The period of `us_clock` is 1 microsecond. Any insight as to why they do not reset is appreciated.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the `output_counter_*` declarations... better still, simplify and post a small compilable/simulatable example if you want to make it easy for us to help.

Comment: Full code can be found here (its a few commits behind though) https://github.com/srohrer32/beamformer_hdl/tree/new_proc. And here is an output_counter declaration. 


**signal output_counter_l_0 : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one obvious problem and one potential problem.

First, as you are assigning `output_counter_r_* <= output_counter_r_* + 1` at the end of the process, these take precedence over the assignments within the if blocks (see [How does signal assignment work in a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060635/how-does-signal-assignment-work-in-a-process)). The counter signal assignment doesn't "take effect" until the process completes here, so anything before those increment statements will be ignored. I'm surprised it worked in sim, actually. What simulator are you using?

The second potential problem is that the rollover condition of the counter is contingent on none of the preceding if-conditions being true. Is this intentional? It shouldn't be an issue unless any `delay_*` happens to be equal to `sample_period*5-1`, but you may want to try splitting it as:

```
if(output_counter_r_0 = 2) then
  data_r_0 <= shift_register_r(0);
elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_1) then
  data_r_1 <= shift_register_r(0);
elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_2) then
  data_r_2 <= shift_register_r(0); 
elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_3) then
  data_r_3 <= shift_register_r(0);
elsif(output_counter_r_0 = delay_4) then
  data_r_4 <= shift_register_r(0);
end if;

if(output_counter_r_0 = (sample_period*5-1)) then
  output_counter_r_0    <= 0;
else
  output_counter_r_0 <= output_counter_r_0 +1;
end if;
```

(Unless that's not the function you intended.)

**Edit for further explanation**

Basically, in a process in VHDL, signals are only assigned when the process suspends/waits (i.e., for normal processes, at the end), which means that only the last assignment to the signal is used. This is useful for several reasons that I won't get into here, but the result is that since you're always incrementing the counters at the end of the process, anything else you've done to them earlier in the process will be ignored. You can code it the way I've shown above, **unless** it was intentional that your rollover condition was dependent on the other counter comparisons - "if = 2, do this, *otherwise* if = delay_1 do this, ... *otherwise* if it's at the limit, roll it over." With that logic, the counter will only roll over if none of the other conditions is true.

If this *was* intentional, the easiest solution would just be to move the increments to the beginning of the process, so they would be overridden by the rollover checks. An alternate (perhaps safer?) solution would be modifying the second if block above to explicitly check for exactly what conditions you want. Up to you.

Comment: 1) I'm using ISim. Could you explain that issue more in depth, and what would be the best way to resolve it?

2) delay_* will never equal sample_period*5-1, so I don't think that should be an issue

Comment: Also, I thought about doing all of the if-statements (assigning shift_register to data_r_*) combinatorially? Do you think this would fix the problem?

Comment: I updated my answer before I saw your later comment(s). The way you have it coded, each data_r_* will be registered on a specific count cycle and keep its value. If you make the assignments combinational, they will only have the value for one clock cycle (or, depending on how you code it, you will create latches, which I don't think you want). I think, based on what you've said, you probably want something pretty close to the code I wrote above.